# URLFOR custom object redirect not working with communities

Tags: visualforce, lightning, community, redirect, urlfor

`{!URLFOR($Action.CustomObject__c.List, $ObjectType.CustomObject__c)}` is not working within a community whilst logged in as the community user.

The page loads but onto the 'Invalid Page'. This operation works just fine from within SF itself, When doing it as the admin on the community the page loads but you must login again first.

I have updated the community user to user a different licenese and profile and the issues still happens.

The Org type is a Development Org, if that helps in anyway

Answer (score 0):

`{!URLFOR($Action.CustomObject__c.List, $ObjectType.CustomObject)}` should  be corrected to `{!URLFOR($Action.CustomObject__c.List, $ObjectType.CustomObject__c)}`

Also, According to [docs](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customviews.htm&type=5):-

> List views are visible to your community users with **Customer Community
>   Plus, Partner Community, Lightning Platform Starter, and Lightning
>   Platform Plus licenses**, if the Visible to all users setting is enabled
>   for views of objects in community user profiles. To make list views
>   visible only to your Salesforce users, select Visible to certain
>   groups of users. Then share the view with the All Internal Users group
>   or a selected set of internal groups and roles.
>
> When implementing a community, create custom views that contain only
>   relevant information for community users. Then make those views
>   visible to community users by sharing them with the All Customer
>   Portal Users group, or a set of community groups and roles.

Comment: kumer, Thank you for the response, the $ObjectType in my code does have the correct __c appendage. It was just my post that didn't

Comment: check the license of the community user and verify it. That might be a reason.

Comment: The user Licence is Customer Community Plus Login. Is there any reason why this would not be ok? the Profile under that is a custom profile with the Objects i want set to have full access